# Given an array of integers A(20). Put Min element in the beginning of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

Task is: Given an array of 20 integers A(20). Find the min positive integer in it and put it in the beginning of the array. Show the initial and changed arrays.

My code is (it works now):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arrayA[20]={6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
    int min=arrayA[0];
    int i, minplace;

    //array's showing in the screen
    cout<<"Array A: \n";
    for(i=0; i<20; i++)
    cout<<arrayA[i]<<" ";

    cout<<endl;

    //min value of array's element
    for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
        if (arrayA[i]<min)
        {
            min=arrayA[i];
            minplace=i;
        }

    cout<<"Min element's value of the array A: "<<min<<endl;

    //array 2
    int arrayB[21]={min,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};

    //array's showing in the screen
    cout<<"Array B: \n";
    for(i=0; i<21; i++)
    cout<<arrayB[i]<<" ";

    cout<<endl;

    int k=minplace+1;
    int n=21;

    for (int i=minplace+1; i<n; i++)
    arrayB[i]=arrayB[i+1];

    n=n-1;

    cout<<"Array with deleted element: "<<endl;
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
    cout<<arrayB[i]<<" ";

    return 0;
 }
```

THIS CODE WORKS NOW.

Comment: What's the actual error?  (and which line is the 40th line? - don't make us count!)

Comment: It looks like your array contains the variable `min` which isn't defined till the next line (in the scope of the array)

Comment: Also, I don't think you're actually answering the assignment - you're not putting the smallest element at the beginning of the array - you're putting the smallest element from the first array at the beginning of an entirely different array.  I'd guess you're expected to re-order the original one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very vague question but I did notice that while you are *using* the variable X, you are never assigning it to anything.

Comment: Beat me to it.. that's probably why some 3rd party tool "codeblocks" is complaining, where there's no actual compile error.  In this case, the variable `x` appears to just not make any sense at all and should probably be discarded.  (unless x is desired position of 0, but then it's still poorly named and should be initialized to 0)  `minplace` is important and should be carried forward.

Comment: @ebyrob, Note: mistake is in the 40th line... int arrayB[21]={min,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};... that is how codeblocks says to me and I cannot understand the problem. I forgot to use X indeed, I had something in mind when I wrote it...

Comment: @Sofie Oh yeah, that one is because you initialize `min` on the next line.  Variables should generally be defined and initialized before use.

Answer (score 0):

This is a much better approach of doing this which utilizes only a single array and is more precise and clean. Hope that this might help someone in learning.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int arrSize = 20;
    int myArray[20] = {6,7,8,9,10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20};
    cout<<"Initial Array:\t";
    /* loop for printing the initial array */
    for(int i = 0; i<arrSize; i++)
    cout<< myArray[i]<< " ";
     /* assuming the first element of the array is the minimum */
    int minIndex = 0;
    int min = myArray[minIndex];
    /* loop for finding the minimum value */
    for(int i = 0; i<arrSize; i++){
      /* condition for checking if the current element is the minimum */
      if(myArray[i]<min){
        min = myArray[i];
        minIndex = i;
      }
    }
    /* swaping the first element of the array with the minimum element */
    myArray[minIndex] = myArray[0];
    myArray[0] = min;
    cout<<"\nFinal Array:\t";
    /* loop for printing the final array */
    for(int i = 0; i<arrSize; i++)
    cout<< myArray[i] << " ";   
return 0;    
}
```